# Creating,using and comparing elements within a button collection

Tags: c#, button, collections

I'm making a Tic-tac-toe project, and I'm having some difficulties. I've only gotten a loose grip about collections, so you can see the problem.

Thing is, I created 9 buttons which change their Background image when clicked, and disable themselves. I've managed to make it run for 2 players, but my wish is to create some sort of an AI.

I need a button collection so I can compare their properties, and avoid the usual one-by-one comparison and massive and numerous If statements.

What I actually want is to be able to test whether buttons in the same row or column have the same values (background images). What I've used so far is an array of strings that describes the sign value, but it's entirely detached from the buttons, and it would take a lot of time to type out all that code.

If it cannot be done the way I imagined it, please do tell. I am open to suggestions, and would be most grateful.

Oh, and if you need any code, or further detail, let me know.

Comment: Please **do** post your code.  It's much easier to help with what has/or could go/gone wrong with it.

Comment: It would be a good idea to seperate your data from your visual representation. That is donøt use the properties of the button to determine whether there's a marker on it or not. Have a collection of markers and use that to render your board.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new to c#, and by that I mean I've been using it for about 6 months now, give or take. I appreciate the heads-up, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate data (array) and presentation (buttons).

> #### Update
>
> [I published a sample console project](https://github.com/gaearon/tictactoe/) that compiles and runs.
>   Its model is separate from presentation so you can take [`TicTacToe.cs`](https://github.com/gaearon/tictactoe/blob/master/TicTacToe.cs) and write a GUI for it.
>
> [image]

You don't need strings; booleans are fine for two states.
In fact, there is a third state, which is empty, so you can use a nullable boolean.

So X would correspond to `true`, O to `false`, and empty space to `null`.
I'd create a class that encapsulates a nullable boolean square array:

```
class TicTacToe {
    const int Length = 3;
    private bool? [][] _data;
    private bool? _winner;

    public TicTacToe ()
    {
        _data = Enumerable
            .Range (0, Length)
            .Select (_ => new bool? [Length])
            .ToArray ();
    }
}
```

Then I'd represent rows, columns and diagonals as vectors:

```
public bool? GetCell (int row, int column)
{
    return _data [row][column];
}

public IEnumerable<bool?> GetRow (int index)
{
    return _data [index];
}

IEnumerable<int> GetIndices ()
{
   return Enumerable.Range (0, Length);
}

public IEnumerable<bool?> GetColumn (int index)
{
    return GetIndices ()
        .Select (GetRow)
        .Select (row => row.ElementAt (index));
}

public IEnumerable<bool?> GetDiagonal (bool ltr)
{
    return GetIndices ()
        .Select (i => Tuple.Create (i, ltr ? i : Length - 1 - i))
        .Select (pos => GetCell (pos.Item1, pos.Item2));
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool?>> GetRows ()
{
    return GetIndices ()
        .Select (GetRow);
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool?>> GetColumns ()
{
    return GetIndices ()
        .Select (GetColumn);
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool?>> GetDiagonals ()
{
    return new [] { true, false }
        .Select (GetDiagonal);
}

public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool?>> GetVectors ()
{
    return GetDiagonals ()
        .Concat (GetRows ())
        .Concat (GetColumns ());
}
```

Then I'd write a function that takes a vector and says if it's a winning one:

```
static bool? FindWinner (IEnumerable<bool?> vector)
{
    try {
        return vector
            .Distinct ()
            .Single ();
    } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
        return null;
    }
}

static bool? FindWinner (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool?>> vectors)
{
    return vectors
        .Select (FindWinner)
        .FirstOrDefault (winner => winner.HasValue);
}

public bool? FindWinner ()
{
    return FindWinner (GetVectors ());
}
```

Now we can call `GetWinner` to find out if somebody already won.
Then I'd write a method to make a move:

```
public bool MakeMove (int row, int column, bool move)
{
    if (_winner.HasValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException ("The game is already won.");

    if (_data [row][column].HasValue)
        throw new InvalidOperationException ("This cell is already taken.");

    _data [row][column] = move;
    _winner = FindWinner ();

    return move == _winner;
}

public bool? Winner {
    get { return _winner; }
}
```

This was all inside `TicTacToe` class.
Your GUI should create it and call its methods.

When a button gets clicked, this is what you may do:

```
private TicTacToe _game = new TicTacToe ();
private Button [][] _buttons = new Button [][3];

const bool HumanPlayer = true;
const bool AIPlayer = false;

public void HandleButtonClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Assuming you put a Tuple with row and column in button's Tag property
    var position = (Tuple<int, int>) ((Button) sender).Tag;
    var row = position.Item1;
    var column = position.Item2;

    // Sanity check
    Debug.Asset (sender == _buttons [row][column]);

    bool won = _game.MakeMove (row, column, HumanPlayer);

    if (won) {
        MessageBox.Show ("You won.");
    }

    RefreshButtons ();
}

void RefreshButtons ()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            var btn = _buttons [i][j];
            var cell = _game.GetCell (i, j);

            btn.Enabled = !cell.HasValue;
            btn.Text = cell.HasValue
                ? (cell.Value ? "X" : "O")
                : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Your AI should also call `MakeMove` and do its calculations based on information from calling `GetRow`, `GetColumn` and `GetDiagonal`.

I didn't check the code, it's only a sketch. (But the [console project](https://github.com/gaearon/tictactoe/) should run just fine.)

Comment: your `GetDiagonal` doesn't return diagonals but returns all squares either counted from top left or top right corner. If you skip the inner loop and use `row`where ever you use `col` -i believe it to be diagonals

Comment: @Rune: True, thanks for the remark. I think it should be fine now.

Comment: I cannot even begin to express the gratitude I feel right now. Thanks SO much!

Comment: @Dreadpool: Not at all, feel free to come back and ask if something is wrong / not clear.

Comment: @Dan: I get this thrown: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool?>'
inside the GetColumn method.Precicely, on the part where the lambda is

.Select (row => row [index]);

Comment: @Dreadpool: Right, since we treat it as `IEnumerable`, we need to use `ElementAt` from LINQ instead of indexing. Fixed.

Comment: Apparently, .SelectMany(FindWinner) cannot infer type arguments, and it tells me to try explicitly specifying the type. Now, since it requires a function, I suppose it should be done with a Lambda expression, but I have no idea how, since it should return itself as is, right? I've even tried with FindWinner => Findwinner, but that makes the app declare not act on the first click of a button, and declare 'You won' on the second, then mark value for the whole column, not just the cell. That might be just because there are a couple more errors, but apart from that lambda, I cant see anything else

Comment: @Dreadpool Sorry for the long reply. I'm back from the vacation and will post a sample that compiles soon. Thanks.

Comment: @Dreadpool I fixed the problems and posted it on Github: https://github.com/gaearon/tictactoe/.

Comment: Specifically, I found a few problems: (1) It should've been `Select`, not `SelectMany`; (2) All rows pointed to the same array; (3) `SingleOrDefault` [didn't behave](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/974d1508-9f27-4f7d-8f5c-c663f0d77a20) like I assumed it would, so I needed a `try-catch`. All of these are fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

What I would use is a game state class that contains the current state of the game. For example:

```
public class Game
{
    // These will have null for unselected, true for circle, false for cross, or something like that
    public bool?[][] SquareStates = new bool?[3][3];

    // Maybe a property to show a game is in progress
    public bool GameInProgress = false;

    // Maybe a function to restart game
    public void Restart() { ... }

    // And maybe a function to check for a winner
    public string CheckWinner() { ... }

    // Maybe another function to make AI make its next move
    // and updates SquareStates.
    public void AINextMove(out int row, out int column) { ... }
}
```

Once you have a class like that, your form would simply contain an intance of Game and then update the array of SquareStates as buttons are pressed and then checks for winner, calls AINextMove, checks for winner again, then updates its own button states with the new SquareStates.